# will_paginate rails bootstrap many pages ellipsis gap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate and will_paginate-bootstrap in rails. How do I use the ellipsis in pagination display as

```
[<][1][2][3] ... [15][16][>]
```

I tried using inner_window and outer_window but it did not help.

```
<%= will_paginate @products, :renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails, :inner_window => 4, :outer_window => 1 %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind - it turns out that the ellipsis show up automatically when the containing element's width is reached. I seem to be answering my questions all the time. Sorry for the spam.